# How to change sharepoint online azure ad group name after azure ad security group name has changed in azure active directory

Tags: azure-active-directory, sharepoint-online

I'm asking for help as I need to rename azure ad group name in sharepoint online
(changing name in aad will not change the name of the group in sharepoint online)

I have found a script made by ADRIAN SIMIONESCU: [https://lionadi.wordpress.com/2016/04/05/how-to-change-sharepoint-ad-group-names-after-the-group-name-has-changed-in-active-directory/]

> Well this is simple really, The code goes through each site collection, identifies groups coming from AD, then retrieves the same group using the SID value from Active Directory and updaes the SharePoint group name based on the value in the Active Directory.

```
param (
 [string]$SPSiteFilter = "Your application URL",
 [string]$SPADLoginNamePrefix = "c:0+.w|",
 [bool]$UseSAMAccountName = $true
 )
 
if ((Get-PSSnapin 'Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell' -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq $null){Add-PSSnapin 'Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell'}
 if (Get-Module -ListAvailable -Name ActiveDirectory) {
 Write-Host "ActiveDirectory Module exists"
  
} else {
 Write-Host "ActiveDirectory Module does not exist. This Script requires this module. Please check that the module is installed."
 Write-Host "To install the module through PowerShell you can use the following command:"
 Write-Host "Add-WindowsFeature RSAT-AD-PowerShell"
 return
}
  
 Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$spWebApp = Get-SPWebApplication $SPSiteFilter
foreach($site in $spWebApp.Sites)
 {
 Write-Host "Site: $($site.Url)"
 # Notice that the SPADLoginNamePrefix variable prefix is used to identify a AD group and also to parse the SID value
 $site.rootweb.siteusers | where { $_.IsDomainGroup -and $_.UserLogin.ToString().Contains($SPADLoginNamePrefix) } | %{
  
  
 $di`spNameSplit = $_.UserLogin.ToString().Replace($SPADLoginNamePrefix, "")
  
 #Get the Account from AD to retrieve to correct name
 $adAccount = Get-ADGroup -Identity $dispNameSplit
  
 $newSPAccountDisplayName = ""
 #Modify the SharePoint Account DisplayName and Name based on the AD SamAccountName OR the Name 
 if($UseSAMAccountName -eq $true)
 { $newSPAccountDisplayName = $adAccount.SamAccountName }
 else
 { $newSPAccountDisplayName = $adAccount.Name }
  
 if($_.DisplayName -ne $newSPAccountDisplayName -or $_.Name -ne $newSPAccountDisplayName)
 {
 Write-Host "Changed SharePoint AD Group: $($_.DisplayName) to: $($newSPAccountDisplayName)"
 $_.DisplayName = $newSPAccountDisplayName
 $_.Name = $newSPAccountDisplayName
 $_.Update()
 } else
 {
 Write-Host "SharePoint AD Group name: $($_.DisplayName) is the same as in AD : $($newSPAccountDisplayName)"
 }
 $adAccount = $null
 }
 $site.Dispose();
}
```

I'm not very good at scripting so if somebody could tell me how to adpat this script to make it work for azure ad/sharepoint online that would be great :)

Comment: Sorry but can't say hello at the top of this topic , so hello there :)